# Make relation between 2 model in 2 different layer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, model, relation

I have an one problem for make relation ship between Identity User and my entity model because the user identity is in the DataAccess Layer and the Entity is in the BusinessEntity layer so they are in the 2 different layer and I can not references the identity user to business entity layer is not good and make cycle error so how can I make relation ship between. 2 object identity user(Application User) and entity model for example imagine that entity is Ticket model that want to has relation to user

I try to solved problem with dto but I can't because I don't have enough information and experience for that please help if you know the solution

Answer (score 0):

In EF your entities aren't in your data access layer.  They belong in a separate component that is referenced by both your business layer and your data access layer.

Comment: My models aren't in the data access layer they are in separated layer my context and appdb context are in in the data access layer

Comment: Then you shouldn't have a circular reference.

Comment: My DataAccess layer should have references of BusinessEntity (my models) to create and configure that with fluent api  database but my models doesn't have references of DataAccess layer because it make circular error so this is my question how can I make relation between model and application user class when the model layer doesn't have references of that ...

Comment: Application User is a model class.  It should be in the same assembly as all your other model classes.